# How to chain access relationship sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

In laravel relationship can be chain and have own method. ex. there 4 model media,poster,image,download.

if i want to access download model from image.

```
$media = Media::first();
return $media->poster->image->download
```

how to do in sequelize?

```
const media = Media.findOne();
media.getPoster() // it stop in here.
```

i defined already relationship in poster model to link to image model.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `media.getPoster()` is a *magic method* that is added by Sequelize automatically to make it easier to query for related data - note that this is a *new* query and not just pulling the data from the existing results. As such, if you want to query for a hierarchy of data then you need to pass in the associations you want to fetch with the `include` keyword.

This example will get the `Poster` results, but will also include the associated `Image` and `Download` models.

```js
const poster = await media.getPoster({
  include: {
    model: Image,
    include: {
      model: Download,
      required: false, //left join
    },
    required: false,
});

// poster.image.download;
```

If you want to include all of these results in the initial query instead of using multiple queries just `include` the associated models when querying `Media`.

```js
const media = await Media.findByPk(mediaID, {
  include: {
    model: Poster,
    include: {
      model: Image,
      include: {
        model: Download,
        required: false, //left join
      },
      required: false,
    },
    required: false,
  },
});

// media.poster.image.download;
```

Comment: how to add where in include image? I need to retrieve only one image with field width `gte 256`

Comment: @davidstephen you just need to add a `where` to the Image include. `{ model: Image, where: { someField: { [Op.gte]: 256 } }, include: { ... } }`